# Funky Interactive Tree Traversal Navigator

Tags: flash, graphics, html5-canvas, jquery-effects

I am looking for some creative examples for interactive methods to navigate a tree hierarchy. Conceptional ideas or some good Flash/Silverlight/HTML 5.0/OpenGL examples of such navigation would be great. I'm not concerned with the technology at this stage.

My problem that is that I need to deliver information to a user in the form of a questionnaire hierarchy. Consider each node in a tree hierarchy as a question where each question answered takes the user to the next level down in the hierarchy of the tree were there are a further number of question(s) to be answered. At the very last node, there will be the final solution.

I have found this useful(http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/tree.html). I would like an interactive version of this with each node been expanded to show further nodes etc. Anyone know if there is anything similar to what I described out there?

Any help would be appreciated?
Dave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many more choices in [this](http://thejit.org/) nice engine. See the demo!